# Read from file c++ and write new line character when needed

Tags: c++, string, readfile, ifstream

Content of the file (test_file.txt):

```
Line1\n 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n
Line2\n 5\n 6\n 7\n 8\n
Line3\n 9\n 10\n 11\n 12\n
Line4\n bla\n bla\n bla\n bla\n
Line5\n etc\n etc\n etc\n etc\n
```

My code for reading a specific line from the text file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream f("test_file.txt");
    string s;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        getline(f, s);

    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Output I get when using this code:

```
Line3\n 9\n 10\n 11\n 12\n
```

Wanted output:

```
Line3
9
10
11
12
```

I want to read one specific line from text file and output it as shown above. And I also have tested tahat if have that string in cpp file like this:

```
string s;
s = "Line3\n 9\n 10\n 11\n 12\n";
cout << s;
```

I get the wanted output.

Please help.

Comment: You could have a look at `s.find(...)` and `s.replace(...)` for inspiration.

Comment: Does the file have line breaks or the literal characters "\n"...`\n` is the escape sequence for new line.  When you write `\n` in a string it means new line.

Comment: Replacing all occurences of `"\\n"` with `"\n"` should do the trick as @Galik said.

Comment: @Drako How should that help?

Comment: bad reading :) - misunderstood

Comment: So this has nothing to do with reading from a file, or a loop, or anything like that. All you are trying to do is replace the text `\n` with an actual newline, in a string?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes exactly.

Comment: Ok well maybe then you could abstract away the irrelevancies from your question? At the moment most of it talks about reading from a file.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I want to use it to read a file multiple times in my code but always another specific line and I also didn't know that it has to be done with replacing  \n with actual new line

Comment: @Žan Reading from a file has nothing to do with replacing the parts of your string. So you should delete those parts from this question and if you are also having trouble reading from a file or writing loops, open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read your third line it will actually contain '\n' sequences. You'll need to replace them with new line characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::string& fix_newlines(std::string& s)
{
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = s.find("\\n", start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
         s.replace(start_pos, 2, "\n");
         start_pos += 1;
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream f("test_file.txt");
    string s;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        getline(f, s);
    fix_newlines(s);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to use this code multiple times. Because if I use this multiple times, 1st time output is right but the all the other outputs are wrong. Can I somehow reset this after every use or how can I solve this?

Comment: @Žan Currently you loop through all the lines in the file and only replace the last one. Move the code to replace inside the reading loop. Or ask a separate question because its unrelated to replacing text

Comment: @Žan I moved relevant code to standalone function, you can simply call it for any line that you need to fix up.